# Summation of squared terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am working on a problem involving the Normal distribution. Can the following summation be simplified any further? It is known that $\delta$ and $\mu$ are constants.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu-\delta\right)^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is $\delta$ a constant?

Comment: Yes,   is a constant (added to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta$ is a constant (like $\mu$), you can use the difference of squares identity to simplify this to:

$\displaystyle \delta \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2(x_i-\mu)-\delta) \\=\displaystyle  -n\delta^2 + 2\delta \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\mu) \\=\displaystyle -n\delta(\delta + 2\mu) + 2\delta \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $